# Not sure why key press is not doing anything

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having some trouble getting a reaction from pressing the D key in my program. I will show and then explain. (Irrelevant things omitted)

Main.py

```
while True:
    process(Cursor,movie,music)

    Effects.List.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Classes.py

```
class BaseClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    def __init__(self,x,y,image_string):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        BaseClass.allsprites.add(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_string)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y


    def destroy(self, ClassName):
        ClassName.List.remove(self)
        BaseClass.allsprites.remove(self)
        del self


class Effects(BaseClass):
    List = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def __init__(self,x,y,image_string):
        BaseClass.__init__(self,x,y,image_string)
        Effects.List.add(self)
```

Process.py

```
def process(Cursor,movie,music):

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        Stage = True
        Stage2 = False
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if Stage:
            if Cursor.rect.collidepoint(370,340): #Start
                if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
                    Stage2 = True

        if Stage2:
            Stage = False
            hitkeys = HitKeys(65,600,"Images/Hit Keys.png") #520
            lane = KeyLane(50,0,"Images/4k lane.png")
            movie.play()
            pygame.mixer.music.play()   

            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                effect1 = Effects(55,0,"Images/Effect.png")
```

I am not experienced in programming so my methods to achieve what I want are very roundabout. As you can see, I want the `Effect.png` to appear when I press D but to only appear during `Stage2`. It just doesn't happen. It would work if I dedented it one part but that would mean it would appear during `Stage`. Not what I want.

Would appreciate if you could help me determine why it isn't showing up in `Stage2`.

Comment: Add `print` in some places - for example before `if key` and inside `if key` to see what's going on. And you could print Effects.List in few places to see if there is expected elements.

Comment: I've also had good luck with the [PDB module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to step through code if you're not using an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `for event in pygame.event.get():`  you set

```
    Stage = True
    Stage2 = False
```

so every time you run `process()` you go to `Stage` (`Stage = True`)

You have to set

```
    Stage = True
    Stage2 = False
```

at the beginning of game (before `while True:`)

---

**BTW:** you will have to use `Stage` and `Stage2` in

```
process(Cursor,movie,music, Stage, Stage2)
```

Maybe better use one `Stage` and assign stage number `1`, `2`

---

**BTW:** there are python rules how to name functions and variables ([PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) - use lowercase (and `_`) for variable names (`stage`, `stage1`, `all_sprites`) and use upper letter in class names. Event `Stackover` use that rules and it use light blue color for class names.

---

**EDIT:**

I made script to test keyboard. Check what you get.

`keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` works but only when screen/window exists.

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

d_pressed = False

running = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                d_pressed = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                d_pressed = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if d_pressed:
            print '> d_pressed <'

        if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
            print '> K_RETURN <'

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            print '> K_d <'
```

---

**EDIT:** sending stages as list - not (separated) values

```
stages = [True, False]

while True:
    process(Cursor, movie, music, stages)

    Effects.List.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

-

```
while True

def process(Cursor,movie,music, stages):

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if stages[0]:
            if Cursor.rect.collidepoint(370,340): #Start
                if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
                    stages[0] = False
                    stages[1] = True

        if stage[1]:
            hitkeys = HitKeys(65,600,"Images/Hit Keys.png") #520
            lane = KeyLane(50,0,"Images/4k lane.png")
            movie.play()
            pygame.mixer.music.play()   

            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                effect1 = Effects(55,0,"Images/Effect.png")
```

Comment: So I did put the `stage` and `stage2` values before `while True:` and it didn't immediately fix the problem. I put `print("Menu")` right after `if stage:` and put `print("Game")` after `if stage2:`. When I run the program the shell prints a bunch of `Game`, no biggie. But when I hit enter to go to `Stage2`, `Game` is only printed once then `Menu` is printed after repeatedly. http://puu.sh/ad5oN.png. Also still no reaction from D, put in a `print` and nothing comes up. And thanks for the tips.

Comment: I tried to use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` and it doesn't works. But nothing happends I never used it :). You still can use `event.key` to get `D`. I put later example in answer.

Comment: See my answer. You could add more `print` to test if `keys[pygame.K_d]` is `True` in different moments.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've found out that the problem is that the state of `stage` and `stage2` does not change properly. Because `stage` still returns `True` when I try to overwrite it with `False`. The shell should be spamming `Game` after hitting Enter right? So I guess the main question now is how do I make the program ignore everything in `stage` when I move onto `stage2`.

Comment: Now I see problem. Using `process(Cursor,movie,music, stage, stage1) python send only values from variables `stage, stage1` to `process` - and now in `proccess` you have new local variables with the same names `stage, stage1`. When script return to `while True` you have variables with old values. You can use list of stages to send it to `process` - see new example in answer.